# How do I make my 'appear from know where' sliding div stay open and wait until clicked again to close? jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, sliding

After I click on a button `div` another `div` appears sliding down the screen with information, but then closes automatically. I want this sliding `div` to stay open until I click on the button div again to close it.

The jQuery code is below :

```
jQuery(document).ready(doContactInfoPanel);

function doContactInfoPanel() {
    jQuery('.info-btn-slide').click(function() {
        jQuery('#info-slide-panel').slideToggle('slow');
    });
}
```

So my question is how can I keep `#info-slide-panel` open until I click on `.info-btn-slide` again to close it?

---

```
jQuery(document).ready(doAddHtml);

function doAddHtml() {
    jQuery('.slide').after("<div id='info-slide-panel'><p>Work Tel :  <br><br></p><br><p>Cell :  <br><br></p></div>");
    jQuery('#info-slide-panel').after("<div class='info-slide'><a href='#'  class='info-btn-slide'></a></div>");
}
```

Comment: If that's how the code is behaving, then there's some issue that you've excluded from the question. Please provide your HTML markup, as well as any additional code.

Comment: Your right I just didn't want to complicate the question. The sliding div stays open when clicked initially. There is another button that opens up a modal window. After I close the modal window and try to click on the button to open the sliding div it opens and then closes again. Any thoughts ?

Comment: The HTML is dynamically placed on the page with jQuery :

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(doAddHtml);

function doAddHtml() {

 jQuery('.slide')
   .after(
     "<div id='info-slide-panel'><p>Work Tel : <br><br></p><br><p>Cell : <br><br></p></div>");
 jQuery('#info-slide-panel')
   .after(
     "<div class='info-slide'><a href='#' class='info-btn-slide'></a></div>");

}`

Comment: Is there some sort of stop function that will keep the div open until clicked again for sure?

Comment: @Michael: Next time edit your question rather than pasting a big block of code in a comment....hard to read.

Comment: sounds like your click handler is getting called twice.  This will happen if it's been installed twice.  Are you calling `doContactInfoPanel()` anywhere else (other than the `jQuery(document).ready(...)`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JhzWr/2/) work for you?

Javascript

```
$('.slide').click(
    function(){
        $(this).slideToggle('slow');
    }
);

$('.open').click(
    function(){
        $('.slide').slideToggle('slow');
    }
)
```

CSS

```
.slide{
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 background: red;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="slide">Hello how do yo do</div>
<div class="open">open</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must be registering the click event twice, and since its toggled it just opens and closed.  can you look at the source and see if you are loading that piece of javascript in 2 places?